# Ultrapower of V by D

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $D$ be a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. The following are equivalent:

(i) $D$ in normal

(ii) In the ultrapower $Ult_D(V)$,
$\kappa=[d]$
where $d$ is the diagonal function.

My question is: how do we know what is $\kappa$ in $Ult_D(V)$?

Comment: Well, $\kappa$ is an ordinal, so it is the equivalence class of a function $f$ that takes ordinals as values. It has to be the $k$th such function under the pre-order where $f<g$ iff $\{\alpha:f(\alpha)<g(\alpha)\}$ is in the ultrafilter. So it should be bigger than all the constant functions $c_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\kappa$, where $c_i$ always takes value $i$. On the other hand, the diagonal function $d$ satisfies $c_\alpha<d$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$, so $d$ represents an ordinal $\ge\kappa$. Normality of the ultrafilter is needed to see that it actually represents $\kappa$.

Comment: If the ultrafilter is not normal, there is no such a nice description of the $k$th function.

Comment: May I have a trivial question about your comment: why oridnal in the ultrapower is a function that takes ordinals as values?

Comment: @user122424 If $f$ is a function which in the ultrapower corresponds to an ordinal, then "ultrafilter-many" of $f$'s entries are ordinals. Replacing the rest with (say) $0$ gives a new function $g$ which is "ultrafilter-equivalent" to $f$ and all of whose values are ordinals. So every ordinal in the ultrapower is named by a function with ordinal values. Not every name for the ordinal has this property, but at least one does.

Comment: I almost get it. But a similar question applies again: why precisely "ultrafilter-many" of $f$'s entries are ordinals?

Comment: @user122424 Cause that's what it means for the statement "$f$ is an ordinal" to hold in the ultrapower (this is just Łoś's theorem).